# Passing string variable in self-referencing function

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, callback

I have this function, and I'm trying to pass the `wordtype` string variable back to the same function when it runs again.

Right now, except for the first time it runs (when I actually feed the string) - it shows undefined for `wordtype`. I call it like this: `rotateWordsA('nouns');`

How can I make the `rotateWordsA(wordtype);` actually pass the string back for the next round of animations?

```
i=0;
    function rotateWordsA(wordtype){
        console.log(wordtype);
        var xyz = "#"+wordtype+" div."+i;
        //console.log(xyz);

        $("#"+wordtype+" div."+i).fadeOut(1000).hide();
        //alert('hi');
        i++;
        //alert(i);
        if($("#"+wordtype+" div."+i).length){
            prev = i-1;
            $("#"+wordtype+" div."+prev).fadeOut(1000).hide("slow");
            $("#"+wordtype+" div."+i).fadeIn(1000).show();
            $("#"+wordtype+" div."+i).delay(1000).animate({
                                //display: "show",
                                //left: "+=500",
                                opacity: 1
                              }, 1000, function(){
                                setTimeout(function(){rotateWordsA()}, 2500)

                              });

                        }
                        else{

                            i=0;
                            rotateWordsA(wordtype);
                        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not passing variable to function call in setTimeout

```
    setTimeout(function () {
        rotateWordsA(); // Pass variable here
    }, 2500)
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you for the added snark. I noticed the non-passed variable as soon as I asked the question. Thanks @Satpal!